# Error using Compass 1.0alpha, Sass 3.3, and Susy 2.1.2

Tags: susy-compass

I used Fire.app before but they haven't updated for a long time.
Then I turn to Compass 1.0.0alpha, Sass 3.3, and Susy 2.1.2
I installed via gem:

compass (1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-import-once (1.0.4)
sass (3.3.8)
susy (2.1.2)

While creating a new project using susy:
compass create --using susy,
an error reads:

```
error sass/style.scss (Line 4 of sass/_grids.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
Load paths:
/******/sass
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/stylesheets
Compass::SpriteImporter)
```

Many articles say a 1.0alpha version of compass will do, but it appears not.
How do I solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where SpriteImporter figures in your website. However, I would suggest installing Bundler, creating a Gemfile to include at least these two:

```
gem "susy", "~>2.1.0"
gem "sass", "~>3.3.0"
```

Then let Bundle install all the gems required. In case you aren't aware, this will be done inside Terminal on mac. The Bundler website explains all.